# Reinforcement Learning - Learning from raw pixels

Tags: h2o, reinforcement-learning

I have been introduced to RL by Sutton's book. In order to further this knowledge I would like to explore how the agent learns from raw pixels and try to implement an example using H2O. I want to use the Java API.

1. Is Sparkling water the distribution I should use ?
2. How do I stream raw pixels to h2o ? How can a ping-pong game, for example, be used to make the h2o RL agent learn  ? What Deep Learning h2o API is used ?

I would appreciate if the answers pertain to h2o as I refer to other literature to learn about RL.

Update : http://h2o2016.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/h2o2016/images/resources/DeepLearningBooklet.pdf

But still I need to figure out how to use Java to stream image pixels from a game to help the h2o RL agent learn. Examples use R and Python mostly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H2O does not support Reinforcement Learning at this time.

You may want to check out something like [OpenAI Gym](https://gym.openai.com/), [Keras-RL](https://github.com/matthiasplappert/keras-rl) (Deep Reinforcement Learning for Keras) or a [Theano-based implementation of Deep Q-learning](https://github.com/spragunr/deep_q_rl).

Comment: But the code needs fundamental algorithms that could already be in h2o. One could combine a few and get the result ??

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan Yes, that's true, H2O could be extended to include a reinforcement learning framework.  No one is working on that actively at the moment though, that I'm aware of.